# Submit button with external link

Tags: wicket

I have two submit buttons inside a form:

```
<input class="submitButton button cancel" name="cancel"
       value="Cancel" title="" type="submit">
<input class="submitButton button" name="Registrieren"
       value="Register" title="Register" type="submit">
```

I would like the first button (cancel) to have a link to an external page. The link is known in the backend (FormController).

I had a look at the `SubmitLink` class. However it looks like that doesn't fit to my use case. I don't want to process the click on the "cancel" button in the backend, just redirect to the external page by integrating this dynamic link into the HTML file.

Comment: Why not just make it a link?

Comment: It has to be a button to be consistent with its design and I think it's appropriate to have a "cancel" button which is part of a form.

Comment: When you say "design" do you mean physical appearance? Because you can style anchors and submits to look exactly the same. I'm not sure I agree that you need to actually submit the form to cancel, unless you plan on logging or using the data in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @jurgemaister that you can use `<a>` for the cancel button and style it with CSS to look like a button.

Otherwise you can add 'click' JavaScript listener to the cancel button to do something like `location.href='/url/to/other/page'`.